# Search Between Two dates in MySql Database

Tags: sql, date, mariadb, vb6, between

I've a problem making a SQL query in vb6 using MySQL database. Basically, what I'm trying to do is retrieve data from the MySQL database into a list view. Although the same code is working perfectly fine with Access database.

I am writing the error that comes:

> [MYSQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver] [mysql-5.5.5-10.4.28-MariaDB] You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB Server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 1

```
Dim list As List Item
ListView1.ListItems. Clear
Dim date1 As Date
Dim date2 As Date
date1 = Me. DTPicker1.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
date2 = Me. DTPicker2.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
If mysqlcn.State = adStateOpen Then mysqlcn.Close

Do Events
Set mysqlcn = New ADODB.Connection
With mysqlcn
.ConnectionString = "Driver= {MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};"
& "Server=localhost;"
& "Database=db_test;"
& "User=root;"
& "Password=;"
& "Option=3;"
.CursorLocation = adUseClient
. Open
End With
Rs. Open "Select* from register where Date0 between # " & date1 & " #  AND # " & date2 & " #", mysqlcn,        adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic
Do Until rs.EOF
Set list = ListView1.ListItems. Add(, , rs!ID)
list.SubItems(1) = rs!Date0
list.SubItems(2) = rs!CashStatus
list.SubItems(3) = rs!TrxId
list.SubItems(4) = rs!To
list.SubItems(5) = rs!AccountNo
list.SubItems(6) = rs!Amount
list.SubItems(7) = rs!AccountTitle
list.SubItems(8) = rs!From
list.SubItems(9) = rs!PrintedBy
list.SubItems(10) = rs!Comission
rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```

Comment: #0. MariaDB <> MySQL !!! #1. The space in `SELECT * ..` is lost. #2. MariaDB does not support date literals enclosed with `#`. You must use single quote chars instead. Also you must not add spaces between quote char and literal. Also you must format date literal to MariaDB date literals format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: After delete the # code, space between select and &, change the literal date format into YYY-MM-DD , the error is not coming, but the result is not being seen. The list view appears empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Rs.Open "Select * from register where Date0 between '" & _
        Format(date1, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND '" & _
        Format(date2, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'", _
        mysqlcn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic
```

Comment: Your code is solved my Problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The `#`'s in your query tell mysql that everything from there on is a comment to ignore, so your query ends with "between ".  Remove them.

Comment: now query is looks like rs.Open "Select* from register where Date0 between '" & date1 & "' AND '" & date2 & "' ", mysqlcn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic

Comment: the error is not coming, but the result is not being seen. The list view appears empty.

Comment: then you likely have the wrong format for the dates; they should be in YYYY-MM-DD format